# Java platformer game doesn't run the initial few lines of code...?

Tags: java

I am making a basic outline for a 2d platformer game in Java... I'm having an issue that started pretty recently! Sometimes, when I run my program, my frame shows up, and everything is set, and you can see the guy, but for some reason the ground does not get "added" (i have an addGround() method which I call in the very first segment that runs). As I got farther into the game, this started happening more and more until now, most of the time it fails and won't show/add the ground! Sometimes, though, it does it perfectly.

This is how it looks when it works:

[image]

This is how it looks most of the time, when it doesn't work:

[image]

So, this is my main class code:
(I have not included all the imports and stuff, just the core)

```
    public BusiWorld()
    {
        this.setFocusable(true);
        if(init)
        {
            ground.addGround(x-300, y+100, 35, 1);
            ground.addGround(x-100, y-360, 1, 46);
            ground.addGround(x+100, y+90, 1, 1);
            ground.addGround(x+400, y+20, 2, 1);
            ground.addGround(x+460, y-50, 2, 1);
            ground.addGround(x+520, y-120, 2, 1);
            ground.addGround(x+460, y-190, 2, 1);
            ground.addGround(x+140, y-260, 15, 1);
            ground.addGround(x, y-280, 1, 1);
            init = false;
        }
        t = new Timer(16, new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                repaint();
            }
        });
        t.start();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        mainFrame.setTitle("Busiworld");
        mainFrame.setSize(600,500);
        mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        mainFrame.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        mainFrame.setResizable(false);
        mainFrame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

And this is the ground class code:

```
public class Ground extends JFrame
{
    private Image groundImg = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("ground.png");
    private ArrayList<Point> groundLocs = new ArrayList<Point>();
    public Ground()
    {

    }
    public void addGround(int xCoord, int yCoord, int howManyWide, int howManyTall)
    {
    for(int i = 0; i < howManyWide; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < howManyTall; j++)
        {
            groundLocs.add(new Point(xCoord+i*groundImg.getWidth(null), yCoord+j*groundImg.getHeight(null)));
        }
    }
    }
    public void drawGround(Graphics g)
    {
        for(Point p: groundLocs)
        {
            g.drawImage(groundImg, p.x, p.y, this);
        }
    }
    public int groundArraySize()
    {
        return groundLocs.size();
    }
    public Point getGroundArray(int index)
    {
        return groundLocs.get(index);
    }
}
```

Comment: don't post such large parts of code! Put then on pastebin rather or on similar service and put only link here.

Comment: @trejder: the relevant parts of the code _must_ be included inline in the post. Only use pastebin for additional stuff. (But I agree this is a lot of code to read through, and Ashok should narrow the problem down.)

Comment: @Mat: I agree. I just don't find the idea of publishing whole class as relevant to a problem! :)

Comment: Ashok you've got to narrow it down more. Can you print something in the lines of code that you think are being skipped? Clearly something unexpected is happening but I usually find that the problem is not wheel I think it is.

Comment: I have narrowed down the code to the parts where I think it's messing up. Thanks guys!

Comment: If you post the code somewhere we can take a look at it. I don't think that the problem is the repaint, it may even be a buffering problem.

Comment: You may want to take a look at http://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/J8d_Game_Framework.html for a tutorial on what is more or less the "de facto" standard to build games.

Answer (score 1):

This is `JFrame` from Swing? I don't see `invokeLater()` for example when you call `repaint()`. Not managing the threads properly in a Swing application can make all sorts of things go wrong. Given the amount of code you've posted, I suggest you deal with threading first - then you can narrow-down your issue if it's still present.

Here's a [tutorial on how to manage threads in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html).

#### Edit:

Basically, anything that modified or causes any drawing to happen must occur before the Swing components are initialised, or on the event-dispatch thread. Code in an event listener or called through `invokeLater()` or `invokeAndWait()` is run on the event-dispatch thread. The code in your `Timer` is *not* called on the event-dispatch thread but does interact with the Swing component, so could make all sorts of things go wrong (such as erasing half your drawing).

Comment: Thanks, I kind of get the tutorial, but could you help me on when exactly I use the invokeLater() method? I kind of understand what it is...